# hive query to find total number of transactions for a customer in last 10 days from his current transactions date

Tags: sql

How to get number of transactions of a customer in last 10days from his last transaction date.
Example:

```
Name  Type     Trx_date
Cody  sale  08/05/2018 12:11:43
Cody  sale  08/01/2018 07:51:49
Cody  sale  08/01/2018 07:51:49
Cody  sale  08/01/2018 07:51:49
Cody  sale  07/28/2018 03:21:32
Cody  sale  02/25/2018 05:19:34
Cody  sale  01/20/2018 06:15:41
Laim  sale  08/06/2018 11:41:23
Laim  sale  08/01/2018 07:51:49
Laim  sale  08/01/2018 07:51:49
Laim  sale  07/30/2018 22:58:13
Laim  sale  05/19/2018 03:21:02
Laim  sale  02/25/2018 09:19:34
Laim  sale  01/29/2018 07:15:41
```

Result needs to be:

```
Name  Type     Last_Trx_date           10d_Count
Cody  sale   08/05/2018 12:11:43          5
Laim  sale   08/06/2018 11:41:23          4
```

Comment: Please post what have you tried to get the better and quick answer.

Comment: @Sharma . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select a.Name , a.Type, b.tdate as Last_Trx_date, count(1) as d_Count from table1 a
inner join 
    (select max(Trx_date) as tdate , Name from table1 group by name) as b on b.Name = a.Name 
where a.Trx_date> (b.tdate - interval 10 DAY)
group by a.Name , a.Type, b.tdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
SELECT
Name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Trx_date ORDER BY Trx_date DESC),',',1) AS last_transaction_date,
COUNT(*)
FROM 
tableName
WHERE Trx_date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would often be approached using window functions:

```
select t.name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             max(trx_date) over (partition by name) as max_trx_date
      from t
     ) t
where trx_date >= max_trx_date - interval '10 day'
group by name;
```

Note that this uses standard SQL.  In particular, date operations vary among databases, so the `where` clause may need to be modified.